# Autocrumb in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I woul like to create autocrumb in CI 
I use this library : http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/137949/

but my problem is like that in my controller. I have 2 functions for example :

```
Class MyControlleur CI_controller {

  public function Shoes () {}
  public function Men  () {}

}
```

I would like to have somethin like that :

`Home > Shoes > Men`

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The best breadcrumb I have ever come through for CI is https://github.com/broncha/codeigniter-breadcrumb

Autoload the breadcrumb library

In your controller construct you add a breadcrumb to your controller

```
class Content extends CI_Controller{
  public function __construct(){
      $this->breadcrumb->append_crumb('Content', site_url('content'));
  }

  public function add(){
      $this->breadcrumb->append_crumb('Add Content', '#');
  }

}
```

In your view `$this->breadcrumb->output();`

Comment: Why is this a better solution than Auto Crumb (besides that you wrote it)?

Comment: well i didn't write it all. The github project is a forked project. I had to make some adjustments for my usage.

Comment: I see, but why should the ts (or someone searching for a breadcrumb solution like me) use this solution? For example, it lacks multi-language support.

Comment: well it fulfilled all my requirement, and didn't do anything *magically*. I had full control of the crumbs. I am sure you can add multi-language support with very little code to it.